# C# The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'

Tags: c#, uri, app-config

I am getting this error while invoking a method of my web service, I dont know what to do anymore :s

Here is the exception details:

> {"The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected
>   'https'.\r\nParameter name: via"}

Here is my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="PowerWeb" connectionString="Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYTABLE;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPW" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>



      <bindings>
        <customBinding>
          <binding name="ZWS_HARMONIZACAO">
            <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions':    -->
            <!--    <wsdl:binding name='ZWS_HARMONIZACAO'>    -->
            <!--        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/">..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>    -->
            <!--        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/">..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>    -->
            <!--        <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">..</sapattahnd:Enabled>    -->
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />

            <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"  />


          </binding>
        </customBinding>
      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://mydomain:8080/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_harmonizacao/010/zws_harmonizacao/zws_harmonizacao"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ZWS_HARMONIZACAO"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ZWS_HARMONIZACAO" name="ZWS_HARMONIZACAO" />
        </client>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you try changing `address="http://mydomain:8080/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_harmonizacao/010/zws_harmonizacao/zws_harmonizacao"` to `address="https://mydomain:8080/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_harmonizacao/010/zws_harmonizacao/zws_harmonizacao"`? (add an `s` to http)

Comment: That gives me another error:  Binding Failure - The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context

Comment: What is your code that uses this? The name `exception` is not defined in the code snippet above.

Comment: Its while invoking a method from a web service..  here is the snippet code http://tny.cz/6e0740b3

Answer (score 8):

You are specifying an `httpsTransport` in the binding, but in the endpoint definition you are providing `http` as a protocol. As suggested in the comment, try changing the `<endpoint address="http://...` to `https`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is giving me another error:
BindingFailure: The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context.

I tried to change httpsTransport to httpTransport and the error was the same..

Answer (score 6):

Change from Transport to None

1. If configuration is part of Code

**BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport** to **BasicHttpSecurityMode.None**

2.If configuration is part of web.config

`<security mode="Transport">
</security>`

**to**

```
<security mode="None">  
</security>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have changed the configuration of the binding like this:

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
 var address = new EndpointAddress(url);
 var client = new MobileServiceClient.MobileServiceClient(binding, address);
```

The endpoint address is like:

http://server101.local/MobileService.svc

And it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem y one project. Simply in your config file change the line:

```
<httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"  />
```

to

```
<httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"  />
```

And all ok, because your endpoint is http.

Answer (score -3):

[Solved] Change from **Transport** to **None**
If configuration is part of code

> **BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport**   to
>   **BasicHttpSecurityMode.None**

Comment: Since you have posted another answer more complete, please delete this one.